# XML Schema example - prefix "xs" for element "xs:element" is not bound

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

The following is an example from: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_schema.asp

```
<xs:element name="note">

    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:element>
```

When I try validate this I get an error:

> The prefix "xs" for element "xs:element" is not bound on line 1 - XML
>   Schema Problem

What's the schema problem with this?

Comment: That's not a whole schema. And perhaps you haven't declared the xs: namespace prefix.

Comment: Since a schema is itself an XML document, you need to define the namespace prefix.  Maybe see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp).

Comment: The site is only showing code snippets. You are expected to know enough to integrate these into your application. (You can't expect to learn any language by looking at a few code snippets, and this applies to XML Schema perhaps more than most languages).

Answer (score 3):

Adding the namespace prefix: xs

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <xs:element name="note">
          <xs:complexType>
             <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string" />
             </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```